# Using passport js 'req.user' in more than one file

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

How to use PassportJS `req.user`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'))`, passport sets a cookie in the browser that are requesting authentication. So, if you are using :

```
passport.initialize();
passport.session();
```

`passport.session` will automatically set the `.user` field in the request object if a valid cookie is received. But you need to ensure that the user is logged in. You can create a middleware similar to this:

```
function authenticationMiddleware(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next(); //req.user will be available to the next middlewares in your route
  } else {
    // Do something to the unauthenticated request...
  }
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://github.com/jwalton/passport-api-docs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a middleware function in which you can authenticate user and keep the user data in "req.user" object. And then you can use that middleware function on all the routes you want to protect.